# List unsold items per customer

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I am working on a Cognos Report to display a list with Customers and Items that were never purchased by those customers, but I can't reverse the association to find the "excluded" Items.

My relevant tables and relationships are:

```
Customers 1..1 <--> 0..1 Sales 1..1 <--> 1..1 Items
```

I have customers A, B and C and products X, Y and Z.

A bought X and Y.
B bought Z.
C never bought anything.

The desired output would be:

```
___________________
| Customer | Item |
|----------|------|
| A        | Z    |
| B        | X    |
| B        | Y    |
| C        | X    |
| C        | Y    |
| C        | Z    |
|__________|______|
```

Any out-of-the-box ideas on how to build a query for such report?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current model won't fit your needs. Try to create a custom "data model" for this query in your report.
Go to Query explorer tab in Report Studio and add 3 queries: Customer, Item, Sales

1. Join Customer and Item by any field, press "Convert to expression" and set something like 1=1 - emulate cross join.
2. Left join Sales to result of (1) by item_id and customer_id (you have something like this, right?)
3. Filter by "Sales. is null" - no sales for pair Item and customer

Result is your dataset.

Comment: This is a working concept, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the performance dropped tremendously from what we expected using a data volume in the magnitude of the tenths of thousands for both customers and products. Do you know if a change on the data model could be more effective?

Comment: I don't think so. Underlying query will be the same.
But you could try to use distinct from Sales. Sales data usually bigger than Customer or Item

Comment: You could also try custom SQL if it's allowed in your setup.